# How to retrieve data and count of data at same time in hql?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to retrieve count and list of data in one query only which I want to write on JPA repository. I wrote it using a constructor and executed using entity manager, but it didn't work. It gave me a QuerySyntaxException. Here is my query:

```
String hql = "select new core.abc(select count(*) from abc as m  where m.Id in :Ids and m.Type  = :Type,"
                + "select max(m.modificationTime) from abc as m  where m.Id in :Ids and m.Type  = :Type )";
```

How can I write such kind of query in JPA repository?

Comment: run this query on the database you have, it contains invalid syntax, first, correct the query and then post here.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out your use case senario is that you want to get all records from table as well as total-count of records and max value of a specific column , you named that column as modificationTime. So onething will be happen in this case, if you want to intract with table with single query, Than you will get useless data for both column named as max and count.

Try This for JPA,

```
@Query(value="SELECT cb from abc cd where cd.Id in (?1) and cd.Type=?2 , (SELECT MAX(m.modificationTime) as maxModificationTime  , COUNT(*) as count FROM abc m where m.Id in (?3) and m.Type=?4) as m",nativeQuery=true)
```

Comment: Thanks ritesh. But if I use this query, what should be the return type of the method of repository. Will I require to create a constructor in my entity abc?

Comment: Also, I can't use native queries. I need to use hql only.

Comment: @chitwan you have to add two transient variable in your Entity named as maxModificationTime and count and their data type will be same of modificationTime variable and int respectively and write update your constructor and make List<Your-Entity> return type for your method.

Comment: But this is native query @ritesh, I need to use HQL or JPQL.